Why are Hindus obsessed with not having desires?
It’s a dream come true for some people to get their desires fulfilled. But most of us donot get the dream we desire or even work hard for. So why does the Hindu scriptures mostly on subduing our desires rather than to help us fulfill our desires ? As someone if gets their desires fulfilled may be quenched of the thirst or may desire even more but eventually the desire will die out. So why is so much non fulfilment of desires?
Also why are people here in this world? From the very childhood we are put in competition to score good grades then to earn more money, etc having pride and honour in our life becomes more necessary as people seek recognition . But when ever we set some goals we are creating a desire which we want to fulfill. So having any goal in life is miserable as every goal you set becomes a failure and there is always the past bad karmas to blame and the hard work done goes in ruin. Are desire fulfilment only for some and not for others . Only few are able to know what good work is get the fruits ?!
God has made mandatory to never reduce the results of bad work but always delay a grand success in life. Why are some people prone to commit bad work that even after doing any good and praying we donot get the sweat glory we want? It pains as a hard worker because if I were not ambitious then it wouldn’t have been the matter but being working and not getting the desired results drives people crazy . Please try to give some explaination to get some improvement in our lives?

There are four goals of life, dharma, artha (wealth), kama (desire) and moksha (liberation).

The wisdom of this work, like unto an instrument of applying
collyrium, hath opened the eyes of the inquisitive world blinded by
the darkness of ignorance. As the sun dispelleth the darkness, so doth
the Bharata by its discourses on religion, profit, pleasure and final
release, dispel the ignorance of men. As the full-moon by its mild
light expandeth the buds of the water-lily, so this Purana, by
exposing the light of the Sruti hath expanded the human intellect. By
the lamp of history, which destroyeth the darkness of ignorance, the
whole mansion of nature is properly and completely illuminated.

Mahabharata Adi Parva Section I
Dharma has been translated as religion, artha as profit, Kama as pleasure and Moksha as final release in the above quote.
There are two paths according to Hindu scriptures.

Yama said: The good is one thing; the pleasant, another. Both of
these, serving needs, bind a man. It goes well with him who, of the
two, takes the good; but he who chooses the pleasant misses the end.

Katha Upanishad I.ii.1
People who aim for dharma, artha and kama want to walk the pleasant path. They are not told to give up desire. They are only advised to follow dharma. Aiming for artha and kama leads to competition. These people are advised to tread the path of dharma so that they do not trample on the rights of others.
The good path
Those people who want to walk the good path, i.e., are aiming for moksha are advised to give up desire. The reason is desire for artha and kama will prevent the attainment of moksha.
Vyasa’s view of Desire

Vyasa said, ‘There is a wonderful tree, called Desire, in the heart of
a man. It is born of the seed called Error. Wrath and pride constitute
its large trunk. The wish for action is the basin around its foot (for
holding the water that is to nourish it). Ignorance is the root of
that tree, and heedlessness is the water that gives it sustenance.
Envy constitutes its leaves. The evil acts of past lives supply it
with vigour. Loss of judgment and anxiety are its twigs; grief forms
its large branches; and fear is its sprout. Thirst (after diverse
objects) that is (apparently) agreeable forms the creepers that twine
round it on every side. Excessively greedy men, bound in chains of
iron, sitting around that fruit-yielding tree, pay their adorations to
it, in expectation of obtaining its fruit. He who, subduing those
chains, cutteth down that tree and seeks to cast off both sorrow and
joy, succeeds in attaining to the end of both. That foolish man who
nourishes this tree by indulgence in the objects of the senses is
destroyed by those very objects in which he indulges after the manner
of a poisonous pill destroying the patient to whom it is administered.
A dexterous person, however, by the aid of Yoga, forcibly teareth up
and cutteth with the sword of Samadhi, the far-reaching root of this
tree. One who knows that the end of all acts undertaken from only the
desire of fruit is rebirth or chains that bind, succeeds in
transcending all sorrow.’

Mahabharata, Santi Parva, Section CCLIV
To sum up people who want artha and kama are not being asked to give up desire. Renunciation of desire is necessary for moksha.
True nature of Sannyasa

Abandonment of all desire-prompted actions is Samnyasa (renunciation)
according to the wise. Men of discernment speak of the abandonment of
the fruits of all actions as Tyaga (relinquishment).

Gita 18.2

Hindus are not obsessed with not having desires. This is a very wrong understanding. How can you not have desires? The thought of not having desires is itself a desire. The thought of getting Moksha is itself a desire. Every activity you do will be driven by desires.
The goal is to gradually transform negative immoral desires to positive moral desires. From positive moral desires to spiritual desires. From that to spiritual practices. And practices will burn away the desires gradually, leading to a state when your ego, desires and karma all burn down, leading to liberation.
In the state of Jivanmukti, the liberated soul behaves like a puppet, where he has nothing to do with his actions at all.

This particular statement is not always true!

As someone if gets their desires fulfilled may be quenched of the thirst or may desire even more but eventually the desire will die out.

If you get hungry, you can quench hunger with food. If you get thirsty for water, you can quench your thirst with water. This might quench your hunger and thirst temporarily, but they keep returning again and again. However, these two are required for sustaining the body.
But certain things are not required for your bodily sustenance and also not quenchable, because they grow on you the more you pursue them.
There's a story from the Mahabharata to illustrate this point. You can read the story of Yayati here: https://archive.org/details/mahabharta00craj/page/36/mode/2up?view=theater
From the Gita,

BG 3.39: The knowledge of even the most discerning gets covered by this perpetual enemy in the form of insatiable desire, which is never satisfied and burns like fire, O son of Kunti.


BG 3.40: The senses, mind, and intellect are said to be breeding grounds of desire. Through them, it clouds one’s knowledge and deludes the embodied soul.


BG 3.41: Therefore, O best of the Bharatas, in the very beginning bring the senses under control and slay this enemy called desire, which is the embodiment of sin and destroys knowledge and realization.


BG 3.43: Thus, knowing Him who is superior to the intellect and restraining the self by the Self, slay thou, O mighty-armed Arjuna, the enemy in the form of desire, hard to conquer.



Why are some people prone to commit bad work that even after doing any good and praying we donot get the sweat glory we want?

Because the fruits of actions are never in your control. That's why you should pursue your duties without being attached to their fruits, whatever they may be, good or bad.
The miseries in life are only present because of desire. If a person eliminates their desire, they won't be miserable in life.
